# Detecting current iPhone input language

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Does anybody knows, can I get the current input language and/or keyboard layout in iPhone application? Can I also get a notification when input language was changed?

Comment: More recent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860553/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-current-keyboard-input-method-on-the-iphone

Comment: You might want to look at this link. http://razibdeb.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/how-to-check-whether-a-character-is-from-english-language-or-not-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 29):

In iOS 4.2 and later, you can use the `UITextInputMode` class to determine the primary language currently being used for text input.

`[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage` will give you an `NSString` representing the BCP 47 language code such as “es”, “en-US”, or “fr-CA”.

You can register for the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` to be alerted when the current input mode changes.

(You might also be interested in the ["Getting Your Apps Ready for China and other Hot New Markets"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=131) WWDC session, and [Internationalization Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html).)

Comment: Deprecated since iOS7.

Comment: Because this method is deprecated in iOS7, its better to use current first responder's method **textInputMode**. Its works the same. See my answer.

Answer (score 17):

You can ask current first responder (UITextField, UISearchBar, etc.) via UIResponder method textInputMode:

```
// assume you have instance variable pointing to search bar currently entering
UITextInputMode *inputMode = [self.searchBar textInputMode];
NSString *lang = inputMode.primaryLanguage;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add an observer to the default notification center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(inputModeDidChange:)
                                             name:@"UIKeyboardCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

This method prints the currently selected input language (like `"en_US"` or `"de_DE"`):

```
- (void)inputModeDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    id obj = [notification object];
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(inputModeLastUsedPreference)]) {
        id mode = [obj performSelector:@selector(inputModeLastUsedPreference)];
        NSLog(@"mode: %@", mode);
    }
}
```

***BUT:*** All the above is not documented and you should not use it in shipping code!

Comment: You might have gotten the neg because you're describing code that can't be shipped using the SDK.

Comment: Interesting, but not useful--if I indeed cannot use in "shipping" code.

Comment: I still don’t get it... Three downvotes for some reverse-engineered information which clearly states it’s non-applicability for shipping apps. Downvoters, are you offended by the information in this answer?

Comment: I'm downvoting because UITextInputMode offers a supported way to do this.

Comment: @Vincent Gable: Please note that this answer was written at a time where `UITextInputMode` was not yet available (iOS 4.2, released Nov. 2010).

Comment: At least this stays controversial 9 up, 5 down :)

Comment: my `[notification object]` returns `null`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

From the Apple Reference Library - "[Getting the Current Language and Locale](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html)":

```
NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString* preferredLang = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` is the official way to get the list of preferred labguages. But I think @Danya want's the name of the current keyboard layout. That's something else.

Comment: Exactly. I need to change the content of the view depending of the current input language. So, I need to have a way to get the current keyboard language as well as a notification when user pressed the keyboard button to change language.

Comment: This is helpful, because [NSLocale currentLocale] wont give you the user's UI language!

Comment: OP was asking for the keyboard language; this has nothing to do with it. Also reading `AppleLanguages` preferences directly is a bad idea; if you really wanted the user's preferred language you can get it with NSLocale.preferredLanguages.firstObject. Note that this does *not* mean that your application is running in this language as the preferred language could be one your app does not support.

Answer (score 2):

In line with the top answers, the following is a generic solution to getting the keyboard language whenever it is changed. Register for the notification `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(inputModeDidChange:) name:UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then in `inputModeDidChange`

```
-(void)inputModeDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
   UIView *firstResponder = [UIView currentFirstResponder];
   UITextInputMode *currentInputMode =  firstResponder.textInputMode;
   NSString *keyboardLanguage = [currentInputMode primaryLanguage];
   NSLog(@"%@", keyboardLanguage); // e.g. en-US
}
```

Where `currentFirstResponder` is from a category on UIView to get the first responder view, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api) SO post:

```
//  UIView+Additions.h 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIView (Additions)
+ (id)currentFirstResponder;
@end
```

Implementation

```
//  UIView+Additions.m
#import "UIView+Additions.h"
static __weak id currentFirstResponder;
@implementation UIView (Additions)
+ (id)currentFirstResponder {
    currentFirstResponder = nil;
    // This will invoke on first responder when target is nil
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(findFirstResponder:)
                                           to:nil
                                         from:nil
                                     forEvent:nil];
    return currentFirstResponder;
}

- (void)findFirstResponder:(id)sender {
    // First responder will set the static variable to itself
    currentFirstResponder = self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is as follows:

- Register your ViewController as a listener to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`

  `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];`
- In applicationDidBecomeActive handler, check the current language using `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` and act upon it accordingly.

This approach gives you what you want and is totally shippable without having to use private API.

Comment: This returns the UI language, not the input/keyboard language.