# Ho to get month/weekday symbols from NSDateFormatter in current language (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, localization, nsdateformatter, region

In particular I'm interested in *shortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols*. I'm using this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray *shortWeekdaySymbols = [dateFormatter shortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols];
```

But if iPhone region format is set to US but language to French/German/any other, NSDateFormatter returns English strings (mon tue ...). But I want to respect the language settings and get weekday names in the current language (standard Clock app does this for example). Is this possible?

The only way I can think of to do this would be to get the current user language (how?) and set locale on the date formatter to this language's region.

Comment: What's wrong with simply respecting the region format? Thats what the standard apps do anyway.

Comment: As stated in original question: "standard Clock app does this for example".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look here
[Detecting current iPhone input language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language)

Answer (score 10):

The only way you can think of, "get the current user language (how?) and set locale on the date formatter to this language's region" is correct. This is how.

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]] autorelease]];
```

Comment: [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];