# Is it possible to detect the current keyboard input method on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know the current input method the user is typing in such as En (english), German, Chinese, etc...  Maybe keyboard type is what I am after, but documentation seems limited on this subject from Apple doc.

Thank you!

Managing the iPhone Keyboard
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting current iPhone input language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In iOS4.2 there is a new class UITextInputMode that is exactly what you want.
(Oops, this is still under NDA. If you have no iOS dev center account please don't read  this answer ;) )

You can query current mode (English, French, Japanese, etc) or get notifications when it changes (the keyboard language changes)

[UITextInputMode documentation (requires log in)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITextInputMode)

Comment: +1 Thanks!  That is what I am looking for, but thats unfortunate it took 4 iteration to come out with that and kinda useless to me if is limited to 4.2

Answer (score 1):

`currentInputMode` is deprecated since iOS7, be careful.

> **currentInputMode**
>
> Returns an instance representing the current text-input mode. (Deprecated in iOS 7.0.)

Comment: is there an alternative?

Comment: See [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language) to iOS7+ solutions

Answer (score 0):

here is a tutorial

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/a-simple-localization-example-for-the-iphone

```
NSLocale* curentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

Comment: In any local, you can have more than one input methods.  This is quite common in asian languages such as chinese input method: traditional, simplifed, pinyin, german, etc.