# Find language of current keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard

I want to find out the language of the keyboard in code. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at this answer:

[Detecting current iPhone input language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language)

Unfortunately, as I far as I know, it is not possible to do *exactly* what you want.

Comment: is there any method to find out then pls help me

Comment: Have you read the link I provided?  The user selects the keyboard and there is not a way to know which keyboard the user has selected, as far as I know.  You can find out the user's preferred languages and the current locale of the iPhone, but not the current keyboard's language.

Comment: Sorry still i do not get the right answer.