# Is it possible to remember and force the last used keyboard in my app a la messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit

Is there a way on iOS to remember if my user used a specific keyboard (let's say Hebrew) in a certain textfield in my app? and if so, would it be possible for me to display that same keyboard the next time he goes to that screen and uses the same textfield?

[I know messages does this since iOS 6](http://www.macstories.net/news/ios-6-messages-now-automatically-selects-last-used-international-keyboard-for-each-contact/)

Thanks

Comment: You should not use Apple apps as an example of what you can do in your own apps.

Comment: Of course. I understand that they may use a private API to achieve this. I'm just trying to give a better explanation of what I mean to accomplish.

Comment: It looks quite difficult to achieve, but you can get hint from following questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4067902/1228669