# How do I retrieve the language of the current keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I was able to retrieve the list of installed keyboards through `NSUserDefaults` and `AppleKeyboards`, but I wasn't able to find out which one is the current user selected. Anyway to do so programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage
```

If you use NSLog, you will see something like fr-FR, pt-BR etc...

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for, but that is deprecated on iOS 7. Do you know what it was replaced with?

Comment: I looked for a new method on the Apple's documentation, but it doesn't give us any method anymore.

Comment: Yeah, so did I. I guess I'll use this until it breaks or I find out a better way. Thanks

Comment: Check [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language) to iOS7+ solutions