# iOS Get Language of Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

Can we get the `language` of the `current keyboard` that user is using.. that is see wether the user is using English keyboard or Chinese Keyboard or some other language one…?

I can get the language of the device but i have to get the user's typing language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language

Comment: check this http://tech.pro/tutorial/970/a-simple-localization-example-for-the-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get like bellow

```
[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage
```

Answer (score 1):

From this  [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLocale/displayNameForKey:value:), you can further get the displayName of the language using `NSLocale`.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[YOUR_TEXTFIELD_INSTANCE textInputMode].primaryLanguage];
    NSLog(@"%@", [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[YOUR_TEXTFIELD_INSTANCE textInputMode].primaryLanguage]);
```

NSLog prints "English (United States)" if the primary language is `En-US`.

Note: `currentInputMode` is deprecated from iOS 7.0. Consider using `textInputMode` like above.