# UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification return nil in ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I want to detect current input mode of keyboard, and change text direction with respect to it (rtl if Arabic, and ltr if English).

In the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(changeInputMode:)
               name:UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification
             object:nil
    ];
 }

-(void)changeInputMode:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UITextInputMode *thisInputMode = [notification object];
    NSLog(@"inputMethod=%@",thisInputMode);
}
```

`thisInputMode` is `nil`!

If I use this code instead:

```
    NSString *inputMethod = [[UITextInputMode currentInputMode] primaryLanguage];
    NSLog(@"inputMethod=%@",inputMethod);
```

It works fine and detects current input mode, but `currentInputMode` is deprecated.

Why `[notification object]` returns `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `activeInputModes` property instead of `currentInputMode`

From documentation

> Each element in the array is an instance of UITextInputMode. Returns
>   an empty array if no such instances have been set by the text input
>   system.

Comment: You can't use it instead because `activeInputModes` returns all available input modes, not current one

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language).

It have some new solutions to obtain current keyboard input mode and don't use deprecated `currentInputMode` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `textInputMode` is not part of the notification object. The notification tells you *that* the language changed.

To obtain the actual information, you need to call `textInputMode.primaryLanguage` on your first responder (i.e. a textField) from the `changeInputMode:` method.